# How to add a Navigation Controller to the MainWindow for iPad in Universal Application

Tags: objective-c, ios4, ipad

I tried to add a NavigationController to the MainWindow_iPad of the Universal Application. placed the Navigation Controller using XIB,
Created a New ViewController (MainViewController)
Created instance in the App Delegate , Referenced the Outlet.I changed the field to pop the MainViewController . Bt its not loading properly .The MainWindows loads and it doesnot loads the NavigationController.

I have another problem too . I changed my Project Name for some reason.When I try to launch the application , It launches ,but "applicationDidFinishLaunching" is not invoked.

Whether I missed any configurations ?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, these should probably be two different questions.  For the first, in applicationDidFinishLaunching, are you adding the UINavigationController's view to the mainWindow  (posting the code of applicationDidFinishLaunching would help) ? For the second question, the MainWindow nib gets launched (either iPad or iPhone). This sets in motion the loading of your application delegate.  Did you change the info.plist so that another nib is loaded?

Comment: '- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    [self.window addSubview:navController.view];

Note : plist details are configured properly

    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}' - This i have included in the iPhone Delegate

Comment: Did you set the Nav controller's rootViewController property?